# Failed to use TypeORM in Angular 2, module MySQL not found

Tags: node.js, database, angular, typeorm

I tried to use use TypeORM in Angular2. So I installed TypeORM `npm install typeorm` and MySQL by `npm install mysql` and now when I run my app I get the following error:  `Mysql package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install mysql --save"`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Thats not possible... Make sure you have both `typeorm` and `mysql` in same `node_modules` directory. If nothing is working try to [checkout this repository](https://github.com/typeorm/typescript-example) which has everything setup and ready

Comment: I know this is a little old, but I’m not sure that I understand this question. Angular is a client-side app. You need a server-side (e.g. NodeJS) app to connect to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use use typeorm in angular2.

You cannot use TypeORM in the browser with MySQL, you have to use the *WebSQL driver*.

To use TypeORM with MySQL you have to use NodeJS.